# Distribute array values into another array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, 1-customer payments and 2-services array, I need to distribute customer payments into each service the customer gets.

```
$customer_payments = array(100,75,125,50);
$service_prices = array(150,90);
```

According to the above arrays, the first service price 150 need to have the payments first from 100 and then 50 from the 75 so the remaining payments will be 25,125,50 And from this for the second service price of 90, the payments will be distributed like this: 25 (from 25) and 65 (from 125) and the customer will have left 110  (60 and 50) on account, if the customer will purchase any other services, the new services will have the payments distributed starting from 60,50.

So far I have done this but it is not working correctly:

```
foreach($customer_payments as $payment){

    foreach($service_prices as $price){

        if($price >= $payment){

            $remaining_price = $price - $payment;
            $payment_left = 0;
            echo 'service price: '.$price.'<br>';
            echo 'payment: '.$payment.'<br>';
            echo 'outstanding: '.$remaining_price.'<br>';
            echo 'payment left: '.$payment_left.'<br><br>';

        } else {

            $remaining_price = 0;
            $payment_left = $payment - $price;
            echo 'service price: '.$price.'<br>';
            echo 'payment: '.$payment.'<br>';
            echo 'outstanding: '.$remaining_price.'<br>';
            echo 'payment left: '.$payment_left.'<br><br>';             

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I couldn't distribute the payments to the services, my code isn't working correctly? So how can I achieve this?